# Author problems with AAS and authblk in LaTeX for manuscript authors

Tags: author

So basically, my authors and affiliations aren't showing up at all, it doesn't work properly if I don't edit the aastex.cls file. The edits I make are commented out lines 849 and 851, the lines shown below, so that I don't get errors about them being already defined.

```
%\def\author#1{\appdef\@author{\make@author{#1}}}%
%\def\affil#1{\appdef\@author{\make@affil{#1}}}%
```

I've also replaced part of the package usage section to include some other things I use, the item that should affect this being:

```
\usepackage[noblocks, affil-it]{authblk}
```

What I would like is for superscripts after each author name, that fit the affiliation lines given. The code being used is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, preprint2]{aastex}
\shorttitle{short title goes here}
\begin{document}
\title{Proper displayed title here}
\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[1]{Author 2}
\author[2]{Author 3}

\affil[1]{affiliation 1 info, address}
\affil[2]{affiliation 2 info, address}

\keywords{some -- keywords -- go -- here}

\begin{abstract}
some abstract text
\end{abstract}


\section{some section}
some text

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a couple of symbols as superscripts for extra affiliation lines indicating some other information, so, for instance, `\author[1,*]` and `\author[1,\dagger]`, and later `\affil[\dagger]` and `\affil[*]`, showing some information.

Hopefully someone can help me fix this! What's happening with this code is that it shows me everything properly, except the authors and affiliations, which simply don't show up at all! Just a bit of whitespace, and I get no errors on compile.

Comment: You should be aware that `aastex` is obsolete and now `aastex62` should be used.

Comment: Thanks, I doubt it will fix my problem, but I will look into it.

Comment: @egreg everything breaks when I try to use aastex62, can't even compile/display the PDF...no idea why. All I really want is a 2 column scientific preprint style, with numbered bibliography and cites, and a couple of affiliation superscripts per author for several authors. This is getting very frustrating.